# ACF filtering data by meta query

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have an api url, I don't really have an access to the code as I'm the front end guy. I came across this json format:

```
"acf": {
  "abc": {
    a: "11",
    b: "12"
  },
  "test": true
}
```

So if I want to filter results by test = true I can modify my query like this:

```
meta_query[0][key]=test&meta_query[0][compare]=like&meta_query[0][value]=1
```

What if I want to filter by abc.a value = 11? What would be the query? Thanks in advance.